# Data Layer Properties in GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm using Google Tag Manager to track whenever a video plays but I'm unsure how to get the video ID to be passsed down into Google Tag Manager. Here's what I'm working with, `uuid` is the video id string whenever it plays.

```
// Registers the event with Google
function trackVideoPlay(uuid) {
  dataLayer.push({
      'event': 'goldfish-play',
      'eventCategory': 'Goldfish Videos',
      'eventAction': 'play',
      'eventLabel': uuid
  });
}
```

I know that eventLabel is getting the correct data and being pushed to the dataLayer, and that the play event is firing, but what do I place inside the `label` field in Google Tag Manager to give it the correct data? The data is available but I don't know how to tell GTM to access it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the variables section, click new, select "datalayer variable" (datalayer version defaults to version 2, do not change that), enter the datalayer key (i.e. eventLabel) you want to extract the value of, then give that variable a name - I usually use the dataLayer key as name, so it is obvious what the variable contains. Then enter your newly created variable in the label field (either by clicking the symbol after the field and selecting from the list, or by entering the variable name in {{double curly brackets}}).